# Using GetValuePrice and receiving error because ref is empty

Tags: excel, runtime-error, ref, vba

I am pulling information from worksheets that are in a folder - all files are using the same template - into another worksheet to create a matrix of the information. 
I am only pulling three cells from each template and the first two are pulling correctly, because they are on one sheet of the template model but the third is not populating and I am receiving an error.(Run time error 1004. Method of Range of Object_global failed") I am not sure if that has anything to do with my error or if it's something occurring before then.

I have the following:

Private Function GetValuePrice(path, file, sheet, ref)

```
   Dim arg As String
   If Right(path, 1) <> "\" Then path = path & "\"
   arg = "'" & path & "[" & file & "]" & sheet & "'!" & _
     Range(ref).Range("A1").Address(, , xR1C1)
     Debug.Assert Var = 0
   GetValuePrice = ExecuteExcel4Macro(arg)
```

End Function

I am receiving an error and when I hit debug it shows me that ref is empty.
(Run time error 1004. Method of Range of Object_global failed")

This is the code i have in the button to pull from the tabs Workload and Project Info from the templates in the folder.

Private Sub CommandButton21_Click()

```
  ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("a166:h500").ClearContents
  ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("j166:v500").ClearContents
 Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
 ProjectInfo
  WorkLoad
 Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
 End Sub
```

I'm not sure what to fix because I run another matrix with the same code but change the file destination and it works.

Answer (score 0):

In my second sub, i was not pulling the correct variable to display in the matrix. I had declared "CC" but was displaying "AA". Therefore changed the AA to CC and it worked.